# Adding to environment.rb through application.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm adding the Devise gem to a Rails app, and one part of the [tutorial](http://sourcey.com/rails-4-omniauth-using-devise-with-twitter-facebook-and-linkedin/) I'm following requires you to add code to the environment.rb file.

I don't have this file in my project, and none of the Rails documentations I've read really cleared the air about it. [Rubyonrails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/initialization.html#config-environment-rb) suggested that environment.rb is a branch of application.rb, but I don't really understand what it is.

Does anyone have a better understanding of what this file is/does? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspect `config` folder. There are both `application.rb` & `environment.rb` inside it